# ¿Cómo actualizar los datos desde mi base de datos en tiempo real sin recargar la pagina?

Tags: php, ajax, base-de-datos

Quiero que a medida vaya buscando se vayan actualizando los datos desde mi base de datos en tiempo real sin recargar la pagina.

Lo estoy haciendo con Ajax, todo va bien acepto que cuando envío los datos al archivo php siempre me da error, ya hice muchas pruebas y descompuse el código para ver el error y al parecer el problema es a la hora de enviar el dato, me dice que el index no esta definido.

Los datos que envio son los que tecleo en un input con id search:

```
$(get_moviesList());

function get_moviesList(movies)
{
    $.ajax({
        url: 'consult.php', 
        type: 'POST',
        dataType:'html',
        data: { movies: movies },
        success: function(result){
            $("#results-movies").html(result);
        },
        error: function(jqXHR, status, error){
            alert("error");
        }
    });
}

$(document).on('keyup', '#search', function()
{
    var valueSearch=$(this).val();
    if (valueSearch!="")
    {
        get_moviesList(valueSearch);
    }
    else
        {
            get_moviesList();
        }
});
```

Si me pudieran ayudar estaría muy agradecido.

Comment: Qué valor tiene movies? En la primera línea llamas a esa función sin el parámetro.

Comment: cualquier caracter, es un input para busquedas, cuando se envia sin parametros se reconoce como "undefined" y valido eso

Answer (score 0):

Ya has intentando con setInterval? Porque si lo queres en tiempo real, debes agregar el setInterval en tu get_moviesList()

Comment: En tiempo real me refiero cada vez que tecleo en el input, pero ese no es el problema, el problema esta al enviar el dato al php

Comment: Pero qué te aparece al enviar datos al php? Lo estas haciendo con MVC? Porque además veo que el tipo de dato los envias como html. Si lo colocas como JSON y lo capturas con un json_decode?

Answer (score 0):

Pude solucionar el problema, pero sin Ajax. No se si a alguien le sirva porque esta adecuado a mi necesidad pero dejare el código:

```
get_Movies();

(() => {    
    document.getElementById('search').addEventListener('input', async function(){
            get_Movies();
    });

    document.getElementById('inputGroupSelect04').addEventListener('change', async (event) => {
        document.getElementById('defaultCheck1').checked = 0
        get_Movies();
    });

    document.getElementById('defaultCheck1').addEventListener('change', async function() {
        if(this.checked) {
            var popularity = document.getElementById('defaultCheck1').value
            get_Movies(popularity)
        }else{
            get_Movies();
        }

    });

})()

async function get_Movies(popularity){
    const resultMovies = document.getElementById('results-movies')
    var valueSearch = document.getElementById('search').value
    var orderSelect = document.getElementById('inputGroupSelect04').value

    if(popularity == undefined){
        popularity = 0;
    }
    const options = {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        }
    }
    const request = await fetch(`/Final_TPI/filter.php?movies=${valueSearch}&orderBy=${orderSelect}&popularity=${popularity}`)
    const selectOptions = await request.text()
    resultMovies.innerHTML = selectOptions
}
```

El codigo HTML

```
      <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="row">
                <nav id="sidebarMenu" class="col-md-3 col-lg-2 d-md-block bg-light sidebar collapse">
                    <div class="sidebar-sticky pt-3">
                        <form action="">
                            <div class="form-input pt-3">
                                <input type="text" name="search" id="search" placeholder="Buscar...">
                            </div>
                            <div class="input-group pt-3">
                                <select class="custom-select" id="inputGroupSelect04" aria-label="Example select with button addon">
                                <option value="ASC" selected>Ascendente</option>
                                    <option value="DESC">Descendente</option>
                                </select>
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-check pt-3">
                                <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" value="DESC" id="defaultCheck1">
                                <label class="form-check-label" for="defaultCheck1">
                                    Mas Populares
                                </label>
                            </div>
                        </form>
                    </div>
                </nav>
            <section role="main" class="col-md-9 ml-sm-auto col-lg-10 px-md-4" id="results-movies">
            </section>
```

En este código lo que se hace es escuchar cada que los elementos reciben cambios, el primer elemento es un input para búsquedas, el segundo select y el tercer elemento es un checkbox. Use este código para enviar al servidor los datos de dichos elementos y obtener respuestas filtradas y ordenadas (según el usuario desee) y mostrarlas en el elemento con id='results-movies'. Puede que existan soluciones mas optimas y estoy abierto a aceptarlas. Gracias